How to add common properties across custom server controls that inherited different base classes
I need a Server Control (named FormLayout here) that renders child controls based on their attribute.
The goal is to be able to write something like the following:
<custom:FormLayout runat="server" ID="myForm">
   <custom:MyDropDownList runat="server" ID="field1" ColumnSpan="12"></custom:MyDropDownList>
   <custom:MyTextBox runat="server" ID="field2"></custom:MyTextBox>
</custom:FormLayout>

This is the current implementation for these server controls: (In reality there will be more types of child server control, not only these two.)
public interface ICommonFieldProperties{
  public int ColumnSpan {get;set;}
}
public class MyDropDownList:System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList,
 ICommonFieldProperties {
  public int ColumnSpan {get;set;}
}

public class MyTextBox:System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox,
 ICommonFieldProperties {
  public int ColumnSpan {get;set;}
}

public class FormLayout:Panel{
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer){
 foreach (Control i in Controls)
    // can't access the newly added common properties such as "ColumnSpan"
    i.RenderControl(writer);
}

I tried to add the common properties by inheriting a common interface, but then I need to cast these child controls to ICommonFieldProperties whenever I want to access properties defined in it and cast them back to Control whenever I want to use the methods inherited from Control. For exmaple:
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
  var orderedControls = Controls
    .OfType<ICommonFieldProperties>()
    .Where(c => c.ColumnSpan == 0);
  foreach (var field in orderedControls){
    // Group them into different wrappers based on some other common properties  in ICommon Field
    // ...
    // render
    ((Control)field).RenderControl(writer);
  }
}

Another big problem is that since this is on .Net 4.8, interfaces don't support default methods so I will need to duplicate every implementation for methods/auto properties in ICommonFieldProperties in each child server control even if they are all the same. Is there an easier way to do this?

Separate FormSlot elements from Control elements.
<custom:FormLayout runat="server" ID="myForm">

   <custom:FormSlot ColumnSpan="12">
      <custom:MyDropDownList runat="server" ID="field1" >
      </custom:MyDropDownList>
   </custom:FormSlot>

   <custom:FormSlot>
      <custom:MyTextBox runat="server" ID="field2">
      </custom:MyTextBox>
   </custom:FormSlot>

</custom:FormLayout>

Since the common properties you mentioned seem to be all layout-related.
If so, it's better to abstract the FormSlot from Control itself, which acts more like a container for setting arranging properties such as the ColumnSpan you mentioned above.
public class FormSlot: PlaceHolder
{
  public int ColumnSpan {get;set;}
}
public class MyDropDownList:System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList
{
}

public class MyTextBox:System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
{
}

public class FormLayout:Panel
{
   protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
   {
      var slots = Controls
        .OfType<FormSlot>()
        .Where(c => c.ColumnSpan == 0);
      // This way you can access the common properties as FormSlot
   }
}


public partial class MyUserControl: UserControl
{
  public MyUserControl()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
  }
user control
   public string FirstName`enter code here`
    {
        get { return FirstNameTextBox.Text; }
        set { FirstNameTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return LastNameTextBox.Text; }
        set { LastNameTextBox.Text = value; }
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyUserControlInstance.FirstName = "John";
        MyUserControlInstance.LastName = "Doe";

        string firstName = MyUserControlInstance.FirstName;
        string lastName = MyUserControlInstance.LastName;
    }
}


Is this an AI generated answer? There is no explanation and I'm not even asking how to implement that user control.  This is also not how .net Framework initialize stuff.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
